# Macbook pro keyboard and track pad with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro, magic-trackpad

Can you please guide me how to use "Command" key instead of "control" key in Macbook pro with Ubuntu 18.04 ?
Also I wanted to use multiple touch capability of macbook with ubuntu for pinch to zoom, drag etc.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Gnome installed instead of Unity, I would download Gnome Tweak Tool if you don't already have it using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

On the right, click on the "Typing" Section. It should be under 'Alt/Win key behavior' or 'Ctrl Key Position'

For the multitouch, it is a little more complicated. If the mouse currently works for the most part but just doesn't have gestures, look into using LibInput-Gestures, found at this link: https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
Just follow the directions there to set up your gestures as you please.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In KDE, you can use System Settings > Input devices > Keyboard > Advanced and redefine what these keys do.